# Securing Cassandra on a public machine?

Tags: cassandra

I am considering a Cassandra cluster deployment to Google Compute Engine.  However one of our principal db clients would be an App Engine app.  Since GCE firewalls do not include App Engine instances (meaning App Engine instances are considered "outside" the firewall) we would need to open ports in the firewall to the Cassandra nodes, effectively putting our database on the public Internet.

Is this reasonable to do?  I have read up on Cassandra's authentication scheme (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/security/securityTOC.html) but I'm certainly not an expert and thus I don't trust that I can properly evaluate whether this scheme is strong enough to protect a publicly available database server.

If this is a bad idea, what's our best alternative?  Writing some kind of authenticating app in front of each database is rather unappealing since (1) we obviously want the db to be fast, so any extra steps in the way are counter to that goal, and (2) it might necessitate custom changes to the standard Cassandra client libs/programs.

Is there a standard practice here?